# Error while running unit test cases through Jenkins: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=11.0.0.0'

Tags: c#, jenkins, visual-studio-2015, mstest, jenkins-mstest

Written unit test cases using MS Test Framework for our project which is on C# and using Fakes to bypass the DB call. Test cases are running fine in Visual Studio 2015.
But when try to run through Jenkins Job it’s giving below error message:

> Error Message:
>   Test method  threw exception: 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Could anyone please guide to fix the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the issue - Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes version 11.0.0.0 was missing in bin/debug in Git repository. Additionally all dll's which are referred for unit test project needs to manually added under bin/debug folder in the Git